# Xcode's Organizer window gets lost, when using 2 external monitors

Tags: macos, xcode, window-manager

The Xcode's Organizer window (**Window -> Organizer**) disappears, when using multiple (in my case 2) external monitors.

- Xcode's **Window -> Bring all to front** command doesn't bring the window back onto any of the screens
- Same goes for MacOS's **Show All Windows** command, when holding the Xcode's Dock icon

The only option for me is unplugging the monitors, or restarting Xcode.

Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Are they all running in the same Space?

Comment: They were, after plugging in the monitors they aren't

Comment: All windows for any given app must be in the same Space for them to behave. "Displays have separate Spaces" is to be avoided if you like to spread your work over multiple monitors.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. Restarting Xcode helps.